# Проблема при импорте cryptography

Tags: python, python-3.x, криптография

Дано: приложение на python3, использующее cryptography. Комп под lubuntu 16.04. Python3.7, собранный из исходников. На нем пытаюсь запустить приложение. Приложение писалось и тестировалось на другом компе (ubuntu 18). При попытке запустить получаю следующее:
Комп имеет разрядность 32-bit. Пробовал переустанавливать cryptography и зависимости с помощью pip. Ничего не изменилось.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<appname>.py", line 3, in <module>
    from <appname>API.Crypto import Crypto
  File "/home/victor1/PycharmProjects/<appname>/<appname>/<appname>API/Crypto.py", line 1, in <module>
    from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
  File "/home/victor1/PycharmProjects/<appname>/<appname>/cryptography/fernet.py", line 17, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes, padding
  File "/home/victor1/PycharmProjects/<appname>/<appname>/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/padding.py", line 13, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat.bindings._padding import lib
ImportError: /home/victor1/PycharmProjects/<appname>/<appname>/_cffi_backend.cpython-37m-i386-linux-gnu.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64  File "<appname>.py", line 3, in <module>
    from <appname>API.Crypto import Crypto
  File "/home/victor1/PycharmProjects/<appname>/<appname>/<appname>API/Crypto.py", line 1, in <module>
    from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
  File "/home/victor1/PycharmProjects/<appname>/<appname>/cryptography/fernet.py", line 17, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes, padding
  File "/home/victor1/PycharmProjects/<appname>/<appname>/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/padding.py", line 13, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat.bindings._padding import lib
ImportError: /home/victor1/PycharmProjects/<appname>/<appname>/_cffi_backend.cpython-37m-i386-linux-gnu.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что делать.

Answer (score 1):

Удалите python, зачем-то собранный из исходников, и установите из репозитория для этой ОС. Здесь он ругается на битность, где-то 32 бита исполняемые файлы, где-то 64. Разбираться дольше.